# Getting SPARQL results as CSV into R

Tags: r, csv, import, dataframe, sparql

I have the SPARQL query outlined below (apologies for the length) I would like to get results of this query into R into a R data frame resembling the data frame available in the preview [here](http://data.opendatascotland.org/sparql), when the query content is pasted into the *Enter a query* window. In a sentence I'm only interested in downloading figures, column heading and first column identifying geographies. When running the present query and attempting to coerce the results in the data frame and use it in gggplot  I keep on getting an error **ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list**, which occurs as the returned data does not resemble CSV file returned in the preview window when the query content is tested. My question is *What should I change in the code below that it results in an R data frame object with values and structure corresponding to the preview table below.*
[image: query results]

**Code to import the data**

```
# Libs
    library(SPARQL)

    # Source the data
    ## Define endpoint URL.
  endpoint <- "http://data.opendatascotland.org/sparql?query"

  ### Create Query and download table for the SIMD rank
  query.simd <- "PREFIX stats: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX simd: <http://data.opendatascotland.org/def/simd/>
    PREFIX cube: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
    PREFIX stats_dim: <http://data.opendatascotland.org/def/statistical-dimensions/>
    PREFIX year: <http://reference.data.gov.uk/id/year/>

    SELECT DISTINCT
    ?dz_label
    ?overall_rank
    ?income_deprivation_rank
    ?employment_deprivation_rank
    ?health_deprivation_rank
    ?education_deprivation_rank
    ?access_deprivation_rank
    ?housing_deprivation_rank
    ?crime_deprivation_rank

    WHERE {

    GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/rank> {
    ?overall_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
    ?overall_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
    ?overall_rank_observation simd:rank ?overall_rank .
    }

    GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/income-rank> {
    ?income_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
    ?income_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
    ?income_rank_observation simd:incomeRank ?income_deprivation_rank .
    }

    GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/employment-rank> {
    ?employment_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
    ?employment_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
    ?employment_rank_observation simd:employmentRank ?employment_deprivation_rank .
    }

    GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/health-rank> {
    ?health_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
    ?health_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
    ?health_rank_observation simd:healthRank ?health_deprivation_rank .
    }

    GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/education-rank> {
    ?education_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
    ?education_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
    ?education_rank_observation simd:educationRank ?education_deprivation_rank .
    }

    GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/geographic-access-rank> {
    ?access_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
    ?access_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
    ?access_rank_observation simd:geographicAccessRank ?access_deprivation_rank .
    }

    GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/housing-rank> {
    ?housing_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
    ?housing_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
    ?housing_rank_observation simd:housingRank ?housing_deprivation_rank .
    }

    GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/crime-rank> {
    ?crime_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
    ?crime_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
    ?crime_rank_observation simd:crimeRank ?crime_deprivation_rank .
    }

  {
    SELECT ?dz ?dz_label WHERE
  {
    ?dz a <http://data.opendatascotland.org/def/geography/DataZone> .
    ?dz rdfs:label ?dz_label .
  }
  }
    }"

  # Make the data
  dta.main <- SPARQL(endpoint, query.simd, format="csv")
```

Comment: What is the server hosting the data?  "format=csv" is common but not standard.  It may be spelt "output".  Ideally ask the server using the "Accept" header of the HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for showing the interest, the server is http://www.opendatascotland.org/. Presumably, I should be able to get the CSV table by providing .csv extension in the endpoint address but I keep on getting information that the returned XML content is not readable. It's odd as the query works when tested via the website.

Comment: It's running Apache Jena Fuseki 1.0.0 (it would have been polite for them to say that as Fuseki free and open source and they don't contribute to it).  They have layered it with some kind of processor on top of the raw SPARQL protocol.  There is a contact email address - you'll need to ask them.

Comment: AndyS, thanks for your comments. I will liaise with them. I was hoping that there will be an easy way of achieving that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may be interested in this problem, after a set of trials and errors and checking with the website developers it appears that working solution would be use the following command to execute the query:

```
dta.simd<- SPARQL(url = endpoint, query = query.simd, format = "csv")$results
```

and the query below to source the data:

```
  ## Define endpoint URL.
  endpoint <- "http://data.opendatascotland.org/sparql.csv"

  ### Create Query and download table for the SIMD rank
  query.simd <- "PREFIX stats: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/>
      PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
      PREFIX simd: <http://data.opendatascotland.org/def/simd/>
      PREFIX cube: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
      PREFIX stats_dim: <http://data.opendatascotland.org/def/statistical-dimensions/>
      PREFIX year: <http://reference.data.gov.uk/id/year/>

      SELECT DISTINCT
      ?dz_label
      ?overall_rank
      ?income_deprivation_rank
      ?employment_deprivation_rank
      ?health_deprivation_rank
      ?education_deprivation_rank
      ?access_deprivation_rank
      ?housing_deprivation_rank
      ?crime_deprivation_rank

      WHERE {

      GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/rank> {
      ?overall_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
      ?overall_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
      ?overall_rank_observation simd:rank ?overall_rank .
      }

      GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/income-rank> {
      ?income_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
      ?income_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
      ?income_rank_observation simd:incomeRank ?income_deprivation_rank .
      }

      GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/employment-rank> {
      ?employment_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
      ?employment_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
      ?employment_rank_observation simd:employmentRank ?employment_deprivation_rank .
      }

      GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/health-rank> {
      ?health_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
      ?health_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
      ?health_rank_observation simd:healthRank ?health_deprivation_rank .
      }

      GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/education-rank> {
      ?education_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
      ?education_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
      ?education_rank_observation simd:educationRank ?education_deprivation_rank .
      }

      GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/geographic-access-rank> {
      ?access_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
      ?access_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
      ?access_rank_observation simd:geographicAccessRank ?access_deprivation_rank .
      }

      GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/housing-rank> {
      ?housing_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
      ?housing_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
      ?housing_rank_observation simd:housingRank ?housing_deprivation_rank .
      }

      GRAPH <http://data.opendatascotland.org/graph/simd/crime-rank> {
      ?crime_rank_observation stats_dim:refArea ?dz .
      ?crime_rank_observation stats_dim:refPeriod year:2012 .
      ?crime_rank_observation simd:crimeRank ?crime_deprivation_rank .
      }

    {
      SELECT ?dz ?dz_label WHERE
    {
      ?dz a <http://data.opendatascotland.org/def/geography/DataZone> .
      ?dz rdfs:label ?dz_label .
    }
    }
      }"
```

This creates the desired data frame for 6505 geographies and all indicators resembling the example below:

```
datazone          overall_rank income_deprivation rank
Data zone S000001 2            4
Data zone S000002 5            3
```